# Host a dynamic website using lambda and Api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I need some advise in one of my use case. I have a website which is based on html, css, javascript. Also there is a form present in the website into which user fill the details and submit the form. The details were getting submitted onto some 3rd party Database. Hence i need to deploy the website using serverless method. As per my understanding i could use s3 to host the static website. But as in my use case there is a form which intereact with DB and its a dynamic functionality so what could be the best approach to deploy the website as serverless if i uses the combination of Lambda,Api Gateway,S3 etc.Please guide.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend having look at this official **AWS tutorial**:

- [Build a Serverless Web Application](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/)

It uses DynamoDb instead a third party database, but its architecture would be roughly same.

Thus, you would host your static content with the html form on S3. The form would be submitted to an API Gateway endpoint that you will have to create.

The API gateway endpoint would integrate with a lambda function. The function would be responsible for reading or writing into your third party database.

So the workflow, would be like in the tutorial mantioned:

```
client -> S3 website with form -> API gateweay -> lambda -> third party db
```

For more details about how to architect serverless apps on AWS, I would also recommend the excellent **AWS white paper**:

- [AWS Serverless Multi-Tier Architectures With Amazon API Gateway and AWS Lambda](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/AWS_Serverless_Multi-Tier_Architectures.pdf)

Comment: Thankyou for responding it was a great tutorial. However , If i have an existing Api Url that is for our External DB then how can i use that Api with the Lambda function. Also Van you provide any lambda function for such scenario.

Comment: Thankyou for your response. It is really helpfull.

Comment: @KapilKaushal No problem. To accept the answer you have to click a "tick" next to up/down vote buttons. It should turn green.

Comment: @Marcin do you think its possible to allow the request to the API gateway from S3 only? How can i make sure that the gateway is getting requests from nowhere else but S3?

Comment: @Marcin the CORS are just for browsers, Can u check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63040554/aws-lambda-access-from-s3-only-with-api-gateway - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Host the static website in S3 & call the DB API directly from frontend JS!