# AWS Lambda Access from S3 Only with API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

What i am trying to accomplish is to allow a lambda function to be executed by a request from a specified S3 bucket. The API Gateway is used to communicate to the lambda functions. I need to allow the usage of of the endpoint based on the S3 bucket only.

I can set up CORS, but that is not what i intend to do. I need more than just a browser security.
All my allowed requests must be coming from the S3 bucket only. How can i create such a policy or validation in API Gateway? Or is there any other way to accomplish this task?

I am explaining more now. So think that i have an S3 bucket which has a static website. I also have a lambda function. Now my website wants some data to be loaded, so i am calling the lambda function using my API gateway. The API is open right now. There is no authentication or CORS. I need my API Gateway to allow request if it coming from that particular S3 bucket only. We don't want the API to just be open. Now CORS are just browser security, so we want more than that. I have searched a lot for this particular use case, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: how can you make S3 make requests on your behalf? Isn't it just static content hosting.

Comment: As it stands, it's not very clear what you are trying to do. Is it to allow S3 to trigger a specific Lambda function when objects are uploaded to that bucket? Is it to restrict the invocation of a specific Lambda to S3 events from a given S3 bucket, and only that bucket? What does API Gateway have to do with this?

Comment: @jarmod  i clearly stated that i am using an  API Gateway, to trigger my lambda function, S3 events are not triggered here. S3 is not making any requests on my behalf, it is an http request that is sent towards the API gateway, we need the API gateway to understand where the request is coming from.

Comment: Ok, what do you mean by “allow a lambda function to be executed by a request from a specified S3 bucket”? Do you mean from a web page that is served from statically hosted content in an S3 bucket?

Comment: that is why we are using an API Gateway right.

Comment: @jarmod i have updated my question, check if that makes sense.

Comment: @Kuldeep so basically you want to restrict S3 bucket access to the Lambda right?

Comment: @salazarin no its completely opposite, i want to restrict the world to use the lambda but allow it only to be accessed from my S3. again I am using the API gateway to communicate.

Comment: @Kuldeep you can put your lambda function inside a VPC, make your API Gateway private and add a resource policy in the API Gateway to restrict access by specifying the vpc (vpcid) to allow requests from. Any request coming into the API Gateway outside the vpc (an IP address not within the VPC) will not allow it.

Comment: @salazarin yes that is what i am asking, how can i create such a policy? I can make the VPC no issues there. I need to understand how to write that policy which only accepts requests from S3.

Answer (score 1):

S3 is not a service that "calls" other services such as Lambda or API Gateway.

I believe what you are looking for is to leverage S3 Events, in which case an event from S3 (like object creation) can trigger a lambda execution. See here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html

Comment: that is not my question, i know about S3 events but as stated in my question I need API Gateway to understand where the request is coming from. The API gateway must should only allow a request coming from an S3 bucket. Do you want me to elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

> *I want to restrict the world to use the lambda but allow it only to be accessed from my S3. again I am using the API gateway to communicate.*

Since you want to restrict the world from accessing your lambda function, basically you need to place your `AWS Lambda` within a `VPC` and make your `API Gateway` **private**. The `API Gateway` will need to have a **resource policy** which is a `JSON` object specifying the `VPC` (or set of IP addresses) that has access to the `AWS Lambda`. Any request outside the `VPC` range will be blocked by the `API Gateway`.

- Create a `VPC`
- Assign this `VPC` to your lambda function
- Create an `IAM` role with the following `S3 policy` to specify which bucket can access your lambda function. Attach this role to your lambda function.

  ```
  {
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
         {
           "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Action": "s3:*",
           "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:s3:::your-s3-bucket/*",
               "arn:aws:s3:::your-s3-bucket"
           ]
        }
     ]
  }
  ```
- You need to make your `API Gateway` private (you will find this option in the settings) and allocate a resource policy to it:

  ```
  {
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
         {
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Principal": "*",
           "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
           "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:{region}:{accountId}:{api-id}/*/*/*",
           "Condition": {
               "StringEquals": {
                   "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-1234"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
  }
  ```

Don't forget to redeploy your `API Gateway` once you make these changes.

**EDIT:** If you want to restrict `S3` bucket access, navigate to your bucket and it will have something called as a `Bucket Policy`. Add the following sample bucket policy to it (you'll need to edit it according to your use case). This policy will deny bucket access to everything outside the `VPC` specified.

Refer this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies-vpc-endpoint.html:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "Policy1415115909152",
   "Statement": [
      {
          "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPC-only",
          "Principal": "*",
          "Action": "s3:*",
          "Effect": "Deny",
          "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::yours3bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::yous3bucket/*"],
          "Condition": {
               "StringNotEquals": {
                  "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc-1234"
                }
           }
        }
     ]
 }
```